# Make batch execute command on each line in my multiple files?

Tags: command-line, batch

I have the following bat:

```
echo >> "log.txt"
setlocal
for /f %%i in (NAMES.txt) do (
  for /f %%j in (HOST.txt) do (

...entire batch processing

    ) >> "log.txt"
  ) >> "log.txt"
endlocal
```

---

NAMES contain something like:

```
NAMEA
NAMEB
NAMEC
```

and HOST contains something like:

```
HOST1
HOST2
HOST3
```

Final result was supposed to be:

```
NAMEA - HOST1
NAMEB - HOST2
NAMEC - HOST3
```

But the actual result is:

```
NAMEA - HOST1
NAMEB - HOST1
NAMEC - HOST1
```

I think it is related to those lines, because for each line at NAMES, it reads the HOST again, and only get the first line, but i do not know how to solve it ? At the second line from the NAMES, it also needs to read the second line of the HOSTS file.

```
for /f %%i in (NAMES.txt) do (
  for /f %%j in (HOST.txt) do (
    )
  )
```

Comment: I'd tackle this with PowerShell honestly. With the batch for loop, each line from each file is going to be iterated but you aren't showing any other logic you are using either though. I assume you'd need some conditional batch logic to only echo from the same line number. When I run your test batch script with both those files referenced with the data in them, I do not get the result you are showing either though. Back when I was heavy into batch scripts, I probably could have more easily figured this out but nowadays I go with the Windows native PowerShell since it's way more robust.

Comment: This is a trivial exercise in Visual Basic Script also. 1. Read each text file into its own array. 2. Iterate through the arrays, taking one text line from each array. 3. Join them together with <space hyphen space> in between. 4. Output joined line to file. To be considered: what to do if the input files have different numbers of lines? What to do if output file exists?

Answer (score 0):

The following suggestion is for to get the same line number from each file!

- Save each line in a variable ("*incrementable*").
- Doing this for each file in a loop separately.

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%i in (.\NAMES.txt)do set /a "_N+=1" && call set "_i!_N!=%%~i"
for /f %%j in (.\HOST.txt)do set /a "_H+=1" && call set "_j!_H!=%%~j"
for /l %%L in ( 1 1 !_H!)do echo\!_i%%L! - !_j%%L!
endlocal
```

Or, one more readable:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%i in (.\NAMES.txt)do ( 
     set /a "_N+=1"
     set "_i!_N!=%%~i"
    )
    
for /f %%j in (.\HOST.txt)do (
     set /a "_H+=1"
     set "_j!_H!=%%~j"
    )

for /l %%L in ( 1 1 !_H!)do echo\!_i%%L! !_j%%L!

endlocal
```

---

- Add this in your code:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%i in (.\NAMES.txt)do ( 
     set /a "_N+=1"
     set "_i!_N!=%%~i"
    )
    
for /f %%j in (.\HOST.txt)do (
     set /a "_H+=1"
     set "_j!_H!=%%~j"
    )

for /f %%i in (NAMES.txt) do for /f %%j in (HOST.txt) do (
     set /a "_cnt+=1"
     rem ...entire batch processing 
     
     rem ...for echo each line in a file in doble loop for /f... 
     for %%G in (!_cnt!) do >>".\log.txt" (
           findstr /c:"!_i%%~G! - !_j%%~G!" ".\log.txt" >nul || echo=!_i%%~G! - !_j%%~G! 
          ) 2>nul
     )
 
rem ...for echo each line in your screen... 
for /l %%L in ( 1 1 !_H!)do echo\!_i%%L! !_j%%L!

endlocal
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`Findstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html%5D)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html%5D) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html%5D)
- [`Local Environment | Function`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html)

  - [`Setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) & [`Endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: I also found that, if i do merge HOST and NAME files, something like:

NAMEA,HOST1
NAMEB,HOST1
NAMEC,HOST1

into a file named NAMEHOST.txt

And use:
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%n in (lparhost.txt) do (

I just cant find a way to use %%n for token 1 and %%h for token 2.

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%n %%h in (lparhost.txt) do (

is not working

Comment: @MateusDamasio Forgive, I didn't understand you.

Comment: I do this a lot at work. Having MS Office I just load each file into Notepad one at a time, copying them into adjacent columns in an Excel worksheet, and have a formula in a third column starting like "=A1 & " - " & B1", copy the resulting column into Notepad and save it as the output file.